# Выдает ошибку missing 1 required positional argument: 'b' при создании интерфейса

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Шифрование методом RSA работало нормально, но когда сделал графический интерфейс, стала появляться такая ошибка. С чем это может быть связано, вот код.

```html
from decimal import Decimal 
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

window.title('RSA')
# Variables for checkboxes/listbox
TextVar  = StringVar(value=13)
QVar = StringVar(value=22)
PVar = IntVar(value=14)
letterVar = IntVar(value=1)
specialVar = IntVar()
digitalVar = IntVar()
enChar = StringVar()
# Checkboxes
LabelClose = Label(window, width=15, text="Закрытый ключ").grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=E)
LabelClose1 = Label(window, text="")
LabelClose1.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=E)
labelOpen = Label(window, text="Открытый ключ").grid(row=2, column=3)
LabelOpen1 = Label(window, text="")
LabelOpen1.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky=E)
LabelEncr = Label(window, width=15, text="Зашифрованный текст").grid(row=4, column=3, sticky=E)
LabelEncr1 = Label(window, text="")
LabelEncr1.grid(row=5, column=3, sticky=E)
LabelDecr = Label(window, width=15, text="Дешифрованный текст").grid(row=6, column=3, sticky=E)
LabelDecr1 = Label(window, text="")
LabelDecr1.grid(row=7, column=3, sticky=E)

# lbl1['text'] = (" ".join(link.split()))
# lbl1['text'] = (" ".join(link.split()))


# Button
button = Button(window, text="Начать", width=12)
button.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky=E)
# Labels

labelText= Label(window, text="Введите текст:").grid(row=4, column=0)
labelP = Label(window, text="Введите P:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
labelQ = Label(window, text="Введите Q:").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

# Entry
entryP = Entry(window, width=10, textvariable=PVar).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W+E)
entryQ = Entry(window, width=22, textvariable=QVar).grid(row=3, column=0)
entryText= Entry(window, width=22, textvariable=TextVar).grid(row=5, column=0)


def gcd(a,b): 
    if b==0: 
        return a 
    else: 
        return gcd(b,a%b) 
    p = PVar.get()
    q = QVar.get()
    no = TextVar.get()
    n = int(p)*int(q) 
    t = (int(p)-1)*(int(q)-1) 
    e = 1
    for e in range(2,t): 
        if gcd(e,t)== 1: 
            break
    
    
    for i in range(1,10): 
        x = 1 + i*t 
        if x % e == 0: 
            d = int(x/e) 
            break
    ctt = Decimal(0) 
    ctt = pow(int(no),int(e)) 
    print(ctt)
    ct = int(ctt) % int(n) 
    
    dtt = Decimal(0) 
    dtt = pow(ct,d) 
    dt = int(dtt) % int(n) 
    LabelClose1['text'] = (str(e)+str(n))
    LabelOpen1['text'] = (str(d)+str(n))
    LabelEncr1['text'] = (str(ct))
    LabelDecr1['text'] = (str(dt))

    # print('n = '+str(n)+' e = '+str(e)+' t = '+str(t)+' d = '+str(d)+' cipher text = '+str(ct)+' decrypted text = '+str(dt)) 
    # print('Открытый ключ = {' +str(e)+ ', ' +str(n)+ '}')
    # print('Закрытый ключ = {' +str(d)+ ', ' +str(n)+ '}')
    # print('Зашифрованный текст = '+str(ct))



button.bind('<Button-1>',gcd)
window.geometry("360x225")

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: в функции `def gcd(a,b)` два позиционных параметра. А что вы туда передаете ?

Comment: без этих параметров не работает часть кода for e in range(2,t): 
        if gcd(e,t)== 1: 
            break
если можно сделать как-то по другому, подскажите пожалуйста